# Update Listview with Object Data

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to put data from an object in code to a listview on the UI but I can't seems to find the right way to do it. I've tried multiple I found on the internet including some tutorial but I always run into the same issues.

Most example are in C# but I code in VB for this project. I have C# experience but I'm not convinced that's the issue here.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="AD_AccountList" >
                <!--<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tt1}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tt2}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tt3}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>-->
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tt1}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tt2}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding tt3}" />
                    </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I tried with and without a template or gridview. Both give the same result:
Either have Blank line, or the table fill with the object name "App.testt"

It seems to be an issue with the way WPF handle datatype but I read that template should basically solve that issue.

My code in VB:

```
Private Sub Test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim testlist As New List(Of testt)
    testlist.Add(New testt("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
    testlist.Add(New testt("ddd", "fff", "ggg"))
    testlist.Add(New testt("www", "eee", "111"))

    MessageBox.Show(testlist(0).tt1)
    Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                          AD_AccountList.ItemsSource = testlist
                      End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class testt
    Public tt1 As String
    Public tt2 As String
    Public tt3 As String

    Sub New(tt1 As String, tt2 As String, tt3 As String)
        Me.tt1 = tt1
        Me.tt2 = tt2
        Me.tt3 = tt3
   End Sub
End Class
```

The messagebox was for testing and it indeed show me the data I request for, so my object is filled up with data for sure.

I'm pretty new to WPF. I'm am moving a software from win32 to WPF but I don't want to do this the easy way so I would like the real way to handle this in WPF if possible.

I don't mind a link to something that can help or reference but I ran out of that in my research.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to fields in XAML, only to properties. `testt` has fields, not properties.

Try changing the fields to auto-implemented properties:

```
Public Property tt1 As String
Public Property tt2 As String
Public Property tt3 As String
```

Comment: is that something particular to WPF? that's working perfectly but trying to understand what it is exactly and how does it work. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: @DrizztDoUrden WPF, Silverlight, UWP -- any XAML flavor. It's not a first-principles thing. Bindings just happen to be implemented that way. The framework creates an instance of the `Binding` class for each binding. It (simplifying somewhat) gets the property you're binding to by reflection, and it just doesn't bother asking for fields. It only looks for properties.

Comment: Thank you. Feel like it SUPER important and that I should have known that from the start... Would have clearly helped :)

Comment: @DrizztDoUrden The XAML learning curve is steep and slippery.